# How do I disable password prompts when doing git push/pull?

Tags: linux, git

Every time I want to `push` and/or `pull` from the terminal (in Linux) I have to enter a password. How do I remove this so that it pulls and/or pushes without the password?

Comment: What is the protocol used by your repo address? ssh? https?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Generate a private/public key pair for password-less authentication.

For Linux, your keys are stored in `~/.ssh`.

If you already have files in `~/.ssh` that's named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, then you already have a key pair. Append the contents of your public key (that's `id_rsa.pub`) to the Git repository's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

```
$ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@git.repo:id_rsa.tmp
$ ssh user@git.repo
$ cat id_rsa.tmp >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

If you don't have the key pair, generate one with

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Read this for further instructions: http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-for-git-authorization/

Comment: When I run the first command I get a:

  You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
  Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
  GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.
lost connection

Comment: This only works for ssh. If op must use https, this process will not work.

Answer (score 40):

Run

```
git config credential.helper store
```

This will store your credentials in a folder inside root. You need to run `git pull`/`git push` after this command and give the username and password for the first time. After this, it will not prompt for username and password. Details at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

As [0xc0de](https://superuser.com/users/109825/0xc0de) wrote in a comment, **this will store the password unencrypted!**

Comment: this should be selected as the correct answer for this question. IMO, the OP wanted to ask about a solution for `https` to avoid having to enter username/password again and again, not switching to `ssh` solution. 1+ for this answer.

Comment: Note that store credential helper stores the password on disk unencrypted.

Comment: Use `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 7200'`, if you want your Linux to store the password only for a specific amount of time. Here, 7200 = 7200 seconds = 2 hours. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562679/10358768

Comment: This doesn't work with git over `ssh`. In such a case, try Jin's solution. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had created a new branch and after that when I pulling, I had to enter the user name and password. Then I resolve the problem re-cloning the branch with ssh address (which is on the relevant repository site).

For example:

```
git clone git@github.com:sshare/GLE.git
```

Answer (score 1):

The default caching time is 900 seconds (or 15 minutes), after which Git will prompt you to enter your username and password again. You can change it as follows (1800 seconds = 30 minutes or 3600 seconds = 1hour). ($ represents the shell prompt as a normal non-elevated user)

$ `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=18000'`

OR

$ `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=36000'`