# How to checkout via SSH on bitbucket

Tags: ssh, git, bitbucket.org

Is there some sort of trick to cloning a bitbucket project via SSH so you don't have to manually enter a password each time?

I've tried following [their docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git) and I was able to get to the point where running `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` reports success.

My Bitbucket project page reports my SSH URL is:

```
git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myproject.git
```

However, when I run:

```
git init
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myproject.git
git pull origin master
```

it fails with the error:

```
conq: invalid repository syntax.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you have read this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/405954/how-can-you-avoid-being-asked-to-enter-your-bitbucket-password-when-you-push-to?rq=1)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are conflating the two Git SSH protocols variants and constructing an invalid URL in the process.

To quote the [Git docs on protocol options](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol):

> To clone a Git repository over SSH, you can specify ssh:// URL like this:
>
> ```
> $ git clone ssh://user@server/project.git
> ```
>
> Or you can use the shorter scp-like syntax for the SSH protocol:
>
> ```
> $ git clone user@server:project.git
> ```

Note that you can't just slap `ssh://` on the front of the scp-like syntax, you need to add a forward slash after the hostname (`server`).

So, with a formal `ssh://` URL you need:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myproject.git
```

or just use:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myproject.git
```

For completeness, see [Bitbucket's docs on the subject](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-RepositoryURLformatsbyconnectionprotoco).